# Viewport settings not working with iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone, viewport

I have tried various variations for viewport settings, but have the feeling something in the CSS causes an overwrite for whatever I specify for iPhone viewing.

What's most frustrating is that I created another site with same CSS and iPhone viewing is not an issue for that site.

This is the [page](http://philippinescali.com/PS/ipad.htm) I cannot get to display in full width for iPhone viewing. I should note that it works fine on the iPad, both in horizontal & vertical views.

Tag used:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

For iPhone I use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

and a media query of:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 415px) { 

}
```

Forgot the iPhone 6 Plus which is 414px wide

iPhone 6's dimensions are 375 × 667 and iPhone 6 Plus is 414 × 736

So to get those to work long view you need your media query to be up to 736 so:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 736px) { 

}
```

Comment: OK, changed viewport to above, but still not able to see full page width in vertical view. Looked into media query, here is what I currently have: @media  screen {
  div#head
    {
    position: fixed;
    }
  /* Don't try this at home */
  * html
    {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    }
  * html body
    {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 1em 0 14em;
    font-size: 100%;
    }
  * html div#head
    {
    position: fixed;  
    }
  /* All done. */
  }

Comment: @BureauSF I would need a JSFiddle or update your original post with all the code and reply here so I know you did that.  Otherwise I am kind of taking a shot in the dark.  If you have what I have, then the problem is your CSS not the viewport/media query.

Comment: @BureauSF oh, now I get what you mean (Maybe?).  Long view (what you call full width) wont be caught by this because for iPhone 6 its dimensions are 375 × 667 and iPhone 6 Plus is 414 × 736.  So to get those see my edit

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback, @SimplyCraig. Just posted CSS on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L9et906f/1/ - what a great tool! I should mention I am trying to render the page on an iPhone 4S - in vertical view.

Comment: So here is a JSFiddle with your pictures in it...http://jsfiddle.net/L9et906f/3/   There is a lot wrong with this page to make it responsive...  You have a header fixed and set to width of 1000px which will always push it off the screen.  You also did not put your CSS within the `@media { /* CSS HERE */ }`  This page needs to be almost re written to get the effect you want.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I have to admit I am a novice to CSS. The only page I want to fit in full width (long view?) is the link above - so I even tried removing all divs (including the 1000px )header

Comment: @BureauSF I'll try and take a look when I have some time for you.

Comment: [sorry, accidentally hit enter while typing] … and instead used tables with width 100%. What's so frustrating to understand is that the long view (page width) show in full frame in iPad, both in vertical & horizontal view, so why not on the iPhone?

Comment: @BureauSF can you take a picture of what you mean by chance so I can see what you are talking about.  I'm kind of confused as to what you mean.

Comment: I found a workaround: added an iPhone only page with a vertical image line up, so able to see full page width on iPhone now!

Answer (score 0):

Well of course it's not going to display the full width of the page, simply because of this line here:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Your page's width is about 560px, while the width of an iPhone screen is between ~320px and ~420px.

Might I suggest you use media queries to make your site responsive?

Something like

```
@media all and (max-width: 559px)
{
    //Insert mobile CSS here
}
```

Comment: OK, I removed the initial-scale=1 part and added the media query, but still do not get a full page width on a vertical iPhone. On horizontal view, the page loads zoomed in, but at least I can pinch out into full width, which is not possible in vertical view.

Comment: @BureauSF you have to change the CSS to work on mobile devices. E.g. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qxy16ozn/)